# load remote url with eyed3

Tags: python, eyed3

I have been working with eyed3 for a while now and I have been using it to extract the genre of the mp3 files this way

```
import eyed3
audiofile = eyed3.load(path)
print audiofile.tag.genre.name
```

Now I have a URL like this, `www.example.com/abc.mp3`.

This does not work and gives me

`IOError: file not found: www.example.com/abc.mp3`

My question being, does `eyed3.load()` not support remote url? is there any workaround for this or any other library that could be suggested.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First check to see if you prepend `http://` to it, if it'll work, otherwise,

As far as I know - you'd need to retrieve the file from the server, first, and then use that.

```
import urllib
filename, headers = urllib.urlretrieve('http://example.com/abc.mp3')
eyed3.load(filename)
```